# Onclick of related list show more link, it's redirect to home page. while using apex:relatedlist and salesforce global variable action

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list, action, dynamiccomponent

So let me explain my issue.

We have a custom object example `custom_object__c`. We decided  to override the detail page using our custom VF page.

SO we have one more VF page that will be home page of `custom_object__c`

In home page we are using

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.custom_object__c.View, custom_object.id)}">
    {!custom_object.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

This link will redirect to detail page.

In detail Page We are using `apex:dynamicComponent` for related list. (Actually we are using custom setting to maintain the related list)

```
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!FundGroupRelatedLists}" />
```

Controller code

```
public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getFundGroupRelatedLists()
{
        Component.Apex.OutputPanel dynOutPanel= new Component.Apex.OutputPanel(); 
        for(Custom_setting__c objRelatedList: [SELECT Name FROM Custom_setting__c 
                                                WHERE Active__c = true ORDER BY Order__c])
        {
           Component.Apex.RelatedList dynRelList = new Component.Apex.RelatedList();
           dynRelList.list = objRelatedList.Name;
           dynOutPanel.childComponents.add(dynRelList);
        }
        return dynOutPanel;
    }
```

[image]

If I click on show more it redirect to home page..

Here I am facing Issue.. Seems like salesforce bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue just removing the VF global variable action in my First VF page.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.custom_object__c.View, custom_object.id)}">
        {!custom_object.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

To

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!custom_object.id}" >
      {!custom_object.Name}
 </apex:outputLink>
```

What I found. When we use the visualforce global variables action. It will append the redirect url with record Id.

Like this

```
/apex/myVFPage?retURL=myfirstVfpageTabURL&sfdc.override=1&id=a044B000000vwUjQAI
```

That is causing the issue. If we just pass the Id in url

Like

```
/apex/myVFPage?id=a044B000000vwUjQAI&sfdc.override=1
```

Then My show 5 more then It work fine... Looks like salesforce bug. I raised a support case. Let wait and see what salesforce say about this behaviour.